# How to Add Validations(Numeric,Date) to a Particular Cell using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to add a Integer Validation, Date Validation to a Particular Cell Using POI.
and validate after the user enters data, show an error message if data is wrong

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered a similar situation for validating an excel file. You can code like this:

```
    if(cell != null){
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                //Validate String as required
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    //Validate Date
                } else {
                    //Validate Number
                }
                break;


            default:
                //Handle Default
       }
   }
```

I suggest that you write separate validation handlers for each type (string, number and date) and just invoke them from your switch case.

Comment: Hi prashant, I need validation on the file itself, we have to show error message if user enters a wrong values in excel only

Comment: You can only read file contents while it is already open. So I think you can read and validate but if you have to show the error in excel itself then it is not possible as you can not open a output stream to an already open file. At best you can show the error on console. But I doubt that is useful in your case.

Comment: Why are you not using the cell data validation using [Data Validation feature of Excel itself](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx)?

Comment: Garry, you are correct, I tried using PHPExcel, it's working , but i have a requirement to use poi for validation